# how can i change Go to text in Quick Jumper antd pagination

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I tried changing go to text in ant design pagination.
document says use `showQuickJumper={{ goButton: "Your text" }}` but result is:

[antd pagination go to text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYape.png)

as you see "go to" text is still visible.
how to hide it?

Comment: Hi @Mostafa, welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have an example where we can see the link with the "go to" text?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `showQuickJumper` parameter affects the display of the quick jump block.
If a component is passed as a `goButton` value, then it will be displayed as a confirmation button.
In order to achieve the desired behavior and change the "Go to" text to another, you need to pass the `locale` parameter and override the `jump_to` property.

```
<Pagination
  showQuickJumper={{
    goButton: <button>Your custom button to confirm</button>
  }}
  total={500}
  locale={{ jump_to: "Your text" }}
/>
```

Unfortunately there is no indication about this anywhere in the documentation. It is relevant for `antd` version `4.17.0` and earlier

Answer (score 1):

You can use locale

```
<Pagination
  locale={{ jump_to: "Your text", page: 'Your page' }}
/>
```